# Hyper-V Core full server image with wbadmin

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-core, wbadmin

Good morning, I am running 2008 Hyper-V Core with 2 guest VMs inside. I want to create a host server image, this will allow me to restore the host Hyper-V core & guest VMs should the hardware fail.

I have tried BackupAssist but their support does not cover Hyper-V Core so I will try with wbadmin from command line.

What I need to know is could I achieve a full host backup [Like Acronis] using wbadmin that woula llow me to recover the server & VMs using the 2008 recovery options?

Any advice, examples of code would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I've posted an article with discussion of how to do this:

http://www.itwriting.com/blog/2887-using-backup-on-windows-hyper-v-server-or-server-core.html

Tim

Comment: Can you summarize the article in your answer?